# Inline formsets Django

Tags: javascript, html, python, django, django-templates

Olá, sou até que experiente em django mas estou tendo um erro que não estou conseguindo resolver, bom o erro é o seguinte, tenho um inlineformset_factory e quando vou salvar ele não salva e diz que is_valid é falso, já fiz de tudo mas a função não funciona.

view.py

```py
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def cadastro_movimentacao_produtos(request):
    nivel = permissao(request)
    nome_empresa = consulta_nome_empresa(request)

    empresa = consulta_usuario(request)

    produtos = Produtos.objects.filter(empresa=empresa)
    
    ItensMovProdutosFormset = inlineformset_factory(MovimentacaoProdutos, ItensMovProdutos, extra=1, form=ItensMovProdutosForm)
 
    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        data_mov = request.POST['data_mov']
        
        form = MovimentacaoProdutosForm(request.user, request.POST)
        formset = ItensMovProdutosFormset(request.POST)
        print(formset.is_bound)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            form.save()
            last_mov = MovimentacaoProdutos.objects.latest('id')

            for inline_form in formset:
                if inline_form.cleaned_data:
                    
                    produto_form = inline_form.save(commit=False)
                    produto_form.question = ItensMovProdutos
                    produto_form.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Movimentação de produtos cadastrado com sucesso!')

            user = request.user.id

            obj_mov = MovimentacaoProdutos.objects.filter(id=last_mov.id)

            obj_mov.update(usuario_id=user)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/lista-movimentacao-produtos/')

        else:
            print(form.errors, 'Comum form')
            print(formset.errors, 'Formset')
            
    else:
        form = MovimentacaoProdutosForm(request.user)
        formset = ItensMovProdutosFormset()

    perm = permissao(request)
    if perm >= 2:
        return render(request, 'cadastros/cadastro-mov-produto.html', locals())
    else:        
        return render(request, 'verificacao/no-access.html', locals())
```

JS e HTML

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.inlineform').formset({
                prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
                addText: '<label id="mais" class="btn btn-success" style="color: white !important; ">Adicionar Produto <i  class="fas fa-plus"></i></label>',
                deleteText: '<label id="lixo" class="btn btn-danger" style="color: white !important; ">Deletar Produto <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></label>',
            });
            $('.datetimeinput').datetimepicker();
            
        })
    </script>

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    {% for forms in formset %}
    <div class='inlineform'>
    <div class='card p-md-0'>
        <div class='card-header border-bottom p-md-4 ml-2'>
            <h2>Produto</h2>
        </div>
        <div class='card-body'>
            <div class='form-row'>
            {% for campo in forms.visible_fields %}

                <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0 table">

                        {% for hidden in forms.hidden_fields %}
                            {{ hidden }}
                        {% endfor %}
                            {{ campo.errors.as_ul }}
                            {{ campo|as_crispy_field }}
                        <hr>
                </div>


            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Form

```py
class ItensMovProdutosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    status = forms.ChoiceField(label='Status', required=False, choices=[
            (0, 'Ativo'),
            (1, 'Desativo'),
        ])
    
    motivos = forms.CharField(label='Motivo')
    class Meta:
        model = ItensMovProdutos

        fields = ['empresa', 'produto', 'qtde', 'vlr_unit', 'total', 'status', 'motivos']

        exclude = ['movimentacaoprodutos', 'usuario']
```

Model

```py
class ItensMovProdutos(models.Model):

    empresa = models.ForeignKey("EmpresaFilial", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    produto = models.ForeignKey("Produtos", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    movimentacaoprodutos = models.ForeignKey("MovimentacaoProdutos", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    motivos = models.TextField(u'Motivos', max_length=70, null=True)    
    qtde = models.DecimalField(u'Quantidade', max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    vlr_unit = models.DecimalField(u'Valor Unitário', max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(u'Total', max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(u'Status', null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['produto']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.produto)
```

Comment: Se a validação do formset está falhando você deveria ver o que tem em `formset.errors`. Assim você consegue entender qual a validação que falhou... Lembrando que formsets têm metadados que são obrigatórios para serem considerados válidos, [veja aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform).

Comment: então, o problema é que o formset.errors está trazendo uma lista vazia

Answer (score 0):

Bom depois de muito pesquisar acabei descobrindo o problema, e é o seguinte, o formset precisa que você referencie ele como management_form então é só adicionar {{ formset.management_form }} antes do loop de repetição do seu formset.

```
{{ formset.management_form }} <--Desta forma-->
{% for forms in formset %}
<div class='inlineform'>
   <div class='card p-md-0'>
      <div class='card-header border-bottom p-md-4 ml-2'>
         <h2>Produto</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='card-body'>
         <div class='form-row'>
                    
            {% for campo in forms.visible_fields %}
                    
               <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0 table">
                    
                  {% for hidden in forms.hidden_fields %}
                      {{ hidden }}
                  {% endfor %}
                  {{ campo.errors.as_ul }}
                  {{ campo|as_crispy_field }}
                  <hr>
               </div>
                        
                    
              {% endfor %}
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

{% endfor %}